# Template Parse Error SMF

Tags: php, html, parsing, smf

I'm trying to add wikiplayer to my SMF Forum but I'm having a little trouble.. I'm trying to put this in my index.template.php:

```
   <!-- Wikplayer http://www.wikplayer.com -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.wikplayer.com/code.js" 
data-config="{'skin':'skins/wikfull/plainBlack/skin.css','volume':50,'autoplay':true,'shuffle':true,'repeat':1,'showcomment':false,'marqueetexton':true,'placement':'bottom','showplaylist':false,'playlist':[{'title':'It%27s%20The%20Most%20Wonderful%20Time%20Of%20The%20Year','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DgFtb3EtjEic'},{'title':'All%20I%20Want%20For%20Christmas%20Is%20You','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DyXQViqx6GMY'},{'title':'Let%20It%20Snow','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DmN7LW0Y00kE'},{'title':'Jingle%20Bell%20Rock','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DitcMLwMEeMQ%23t%3D36'},{'title':'Driving%20Home%20For%20Christmas','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DczhZbqpyBm8%23t%3D27'},{'title':'Merry%20Christmas%20Everybody','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D0A8KT365wlA'},{'title':'Winter%20Wonderland','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DSHE0Jo82_34%23t%3D56'},{'title':'Santa%20Baby','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dg7T0IK99ELs'},{'title':'It%27s%20Beginning%20To%20Look%20Alot%20Like%20Christmas','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DcHh7pW29Fy8'},{'title':'Christmas','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D5aw2yuYAKoE'},{'title':'Jingle%20Bells','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DVKtOBLvPs5Q'},{'title':'Run%20Run%20Rudolph','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dl849CulLhGQ'},{'title':'Baby%20It%27s%20Cold%20Outside','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D2Rhvtzzmq-Y'},{'title':'Rocking%20Around%20The%20Christmas%20Tree','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DbnIqLlBwzrc%23t%3D15'},{'title':'Silent%20Night','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DPGjByOI9Iqw'},{'title':'Holly%20Jolly%20Christmas','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DKjiMMDZoKmY'},{'title':'Have%20Yourself%20A%20Merry%20Little%20Christmas','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DnZ6yQgBvuoI'},{'title':'Santa%20Claus%20Is%20Coming%20To%20Town','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DSnA52s7qceM'},{'title':'Last%20Christmas','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DE8gmARGvPlI'},{'title':'Merry%20Christmas%20Everyone','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D5PkUWkxGWj0'},{'title':'Shake%20Up%20Christmas','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DJ-8VCL4uSUc'},{'title':'Deck%20The%20Halls','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D3-ykZUb3AEE'},{'title':'Carol%20Of%20The%20Bells%20(Pentatonix)','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DVOGByYObUqE'},{'title':'Rudolph%20The%20Red%20Nose%20Reindeer','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D0byH9h1ClBY'},{'title':'The%20Christmas%20Song','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DSOszvL9lgSs'},{'title':'I%20Wish%20It%20Could%20Be%20Christmas%20Everyday','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DZoxQ4Ul_DME'},{'title':'Do%20They%20Know%20It%27s%20Christmas','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D1AcD7hho9fs'},{'title':'Feliz%20Navidad','url':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DQ6ziiLE92Zg'}]}" ></script>
<!-- Wikplayer code end -->
```

But I'm getting this parse error all the time:

```
    Template Parse Error!

There was a problem loading the /Themes/zone99/index.template.php template or language file. Please check the syntax and try again - remember, single quotes (') often have to be escaped with a slash (\). To see more specific error information from PHP, try accessing the file directly.

You may want to try to refresh this page or use the default theme.
syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'
```

If I add this code outside the ?> right at the end it will work but then all the forum fonts seem bigger, too big... Can anyone guide me in simple terms to solve this problem? Thank you!

Also I will include my index.template.php @ https://www.mediafire.com/?vj0jpbn7cae9of0

Comment: Anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting parse error. That means you are missing colon `;` or apostrophe `'` somewhere. look for these if the problem persists try writing the script inside an `echo` statement.

```
echo '<script> your script here</script>'
```